# Header wont stretch all the way

Tags: html, header

http://gyazo.com/17f61b8da9a1dab18c69ef1810920817

```
body {
    font-family: 'Courier-New', Courier, monospace;
    background-image:url('images/bg.png');
}

p {
    color: #fff;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

a:hover {
    color: #8e00d9;
}

/* Header */

header {
    background: url('images/swirl.png');
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px #000;

}

header h1 {
    margin: auto;
    background: url('images/logo.png') no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 120px;
}

/* Navigation Top */
```

My header does not stretch all the way....

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Green Cup Of Tea</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>
                Logo here
            </h1>
            <div id="navtop">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Images of the code? You've got to be kidding. Remove the margin / padding from body.

Comment: aha, got it, thanks, forgot I usually use a reset.css but I don't have it on my pc yet.

Comment: Please insert the code here, and embed the images in your question.  Actually, you should probably have a "?" somewhere in there to make this a question.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` and it should stretch out all the way.

I recommend reseting the code. Simpliest way to do that is adding this code on top in your css file:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

[Source.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple fix suggestions:

1. Consider using a reset, either [this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/).
2. If not, just include this CSS in the top:

   ```
    * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   ```